# How do I grab all the request parameters in Catalyst?

Tags: perl, parameters, request, catalyst

Specifically I'm trying to capture all the POST parameters from a payment gateway as a single string, and then parse them looking for the string 'ERROR'.

I'm aware that there's a `$c->request->parameters` method, but I'm not quite sure how its used and I couldn't figure it out from the CPAN documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns a hash reference with the necessary data

```
my $hashref = $c->request->parameters;
```

A form with:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="joe" />
```

Would result in a hashref like:

```
my $hashref = {
    username => "joe", 
};
```